# Get actual quota limit from youtube v3 API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, quota

I would like to fetch from youtube api my actual quota limit. Is there any possibility for this? When I open up this page: https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/?noredirect&pli=1#project:376690840287:quotas
I see my limit, but how can I get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such Historical Quota Usage API exists.

You should avoiding quota issues as suggested at https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota-issues_9.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this
[YouTube Data API (v3) - Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost)

Comment: You should include the information that the OP would get out of watching the video. If the URL changes then it would be useless to future readers ...