# How to see the remaining quota on api youtube v3

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I rest an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24929445/get-actual-quota-limit-from-youtube-v3-api) which for me has remained unanswered (I do not know if it is possible to go back with an old question on SO).
I hope the weather will have done its job.
I searched a lot on the internet but without success.
I'd like to know if it's possible, through an API request, to get the remaining daily quota on a youtube V3 project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible at this time. The most that you can do is use the YouTube API's [Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) to see how much quota you are using in a day and estimate how much you have left. Hopefully, YouTube will add this feature in the future. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Thank you @Jobob Cavin, I had hope but I suspected it a bit ... I hope they will see this feature soon on youtube (I think a lot of people will like to use it). Have a good day!

Comment: @MickaelLherminez No problem! Yeah, I totally agree. This is definitely a feature that developers working with this API need. You have a good day as well!

Answer (score 5):

@MickaelLherminez You can find out your daily quota usage and limit in your Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com).

Once you select your project, go to "Dashboard" and click on "YouTube Data API v3" below your graphs.

Once you click it, you can find your quota information in the "Quotas" block on the left side just below what service you're using (in this case YouTube Data API v3)

Comment: Thanks @RandomHashTags, that's what I'm doing already but I think it can help other people. Have a good day!